# setsockopt before connect for reactor.connectTCP

Tags: python, twisted

I have a small python client which needs a setsockopt after create_socket, but before connect. The non-twisted python code is as follows. How can this be expressed in a twisted environment?

```
    create_socket (socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    socket.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, 24,1)                        
    socket.bind((clientip, 0))                         
    connect ((serverip,serverport))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `twisted` you can use the `reactor.adoptStreamPort`:

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
socket.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, 24,1) 
s.bind((serverip, serverport))    
s.listen(1)
port = reactor.adoptStreamPort(
       s.fileno(), AF_INET, YourFactory())
```

I don't really understand your code if you are building a listen socket or connect socket. I assume it is a listen socket. 
More details can be found here: http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/12.2.0/api/twisted.internet.interfaces.IReactorSocket.html

Comment: Thanks! The setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, 24,1) is for using IP_BINDANY. This allows binding of a non local IP to a socket, useful when you want to send out and receive packets on behalf of another host. eg: squid. So this is a connect socket, but before connecting a non-local bind has to be performed.

Comment: Note this example code leaks a file descriptor.  After `adoptStreamPort`, close `s`.

Comment: I think you actually want `adoptStreamConnection`, not `adoptStreamPort` if it's an existing *connection* rather than a listening port.