# how to call setsockopt before reactor.connectTCP

Tags: python, sockets, twisted

I want to write TCP Client Protocol, but I want to call *setsockopt* before I run `ConnectTCP`, how can I do that.

```
reactor.connectTCP(
 host=HOST,
 port=PORT,
 factory=TEST,
 timeout=30,
 bindAddress=(my_addr, 0))
```

I only know I can use `setsockopt` in `Protcol` like

```
self.transport.getHandle().setsockopt()
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12542700/setsockopt-before-connect-for-reactor-connecttcp/24280260#24280260) has some answer, but it's for server side, what I want is client side code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
connector = reactor.connectTCP(
            host=IP,
            port=PORT,
            factory=DemoFactory,
            timeout=30,
            bindAddress=(LOCAL_IP, 0))

connector.transport.getHandle().setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_MD5SIG, md5sig)
reactor.run()
```

through twisted source code, i got this solution, it works!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Similar to `adoptStreamPort` as discussed in the linked question, there is `adoptStreamConnection`.

Comment: can you give me an example of it. i want to setsockopt at the beginning of the connection, not a connection is already connected.

Comment: The example would be almost identical to the example in the other question - apart from the specific socket option you want to set, which you haven't included in your question.